# Forward traffic on specific network interface to specific host

Tags: iptables, portforwarding

This machine has two interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`. There is a default gateway on `eth0`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I need to set up rules with `iptables` to proxy all incoming traffic on `eth1` to `10.0.1.1`.

Note that `eth0` is associated with a static IP address `10.0.2.2` while `eth1` is dynamic.

There is a guide on [port forwarding with netfilter](http://kreiger.linuxgods.com/kiki/?Port+forwarding+with+netfilter) that explains how to do this in a slightly simpler setup, but I can't figure out how to go from their example to mine.

Comment: Not a programming question. Better suited for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building upon [the link](http://kreiger.linuxgods.com/kiki/?Port%20forwarding%20with%20netfilter) you supplied, with the exception of [using the `conntrack` module rather than the `state` module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108169):

```
# Activate forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# Forward packets coming in from the outside
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -i eth1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.1
# Make responses on the internal network go through the firewall
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.1.1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.2.2
# Allow forwarded packets
iptables        -A FORWARD     -p tcp -d 10.0.1.1 -j ACCEPT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED
```

In order to disable [reverse path filtering](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html) in the kernel, follow the steps described [here](http://www.tolaris.com/2009/07/13/disabling-reverse-path-filtering-in-complex-networks/). I think that in your case, modifying the value of `net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter` to 0 via [`sysctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) would suffice.
Note that this workaround is a bit of a security hole. A better approach would be to change the network structure itself.

Comment: I can't get this to work (no traffic ever leaves the machine; I get "martian source" log messages), but I think that in my particular use-case I can probably simplify my setup and remove ``eth1``.

Comment: What is the complete exact log message that you get? Also, do you intentionally have a double entry for `10.0.2.0` in your routing table? Are both interfaces actually connected to the same internal network? Can you explain what's the bigger picture here, i.e. what exactly are you trying to achieve and how you want your setup to look?

Comment: The routing table entries are for different interfaces (only one sees traffic from the internet). But I realized that I can easily match on ``! 10.0.0.0/16`` and simply receive all traffic on a single interface (this is a virtualized environment). In other words, I'm not sure my question makes so much sense.

Comment: The routes should be different for each interface. What networks are connected to each interface?

Comment: They're both connected to the same network, but ``eth1`` also sees incoming internet traffic.

Comment: So what's the logic behind having two such interfaces? What's the complete exact "martian source" log message that you get?

Comment: "IPv4: martian source 10.0.1.1 from <internet ip>, on dev eth1"

Comment: I think that due to its routing table, the machine doesn't expect to receive IP packets with <internet IP> from `eth1`. See my answer for a possible workaround.